# Is this pair of equations impossible to solve for x? $y_1 = x_2 - v^{\pm 1}e^{-x_1}$, or equivalently $(x - y)c^{\exp(-x)} = z$

Tags: systems-of-equations, inverse-function, elementary-functions

**Original:**

I'm trying to solve the following for $x_1$ and $x_2$,

$$ y_1 = x_2 - v\, e^{-x_1} $$
$$ y_2 = x_1 - \frac{1}{v}\, e^{-x_2} $$

in terms of $y_1$, $y_2$, and $v$, which are known and real, and where $v$ is positive.  This should be determined and the form seems familiar, but I can't find an inverse.  Does anyone know how to go about solving them?  Does a solution even exist?

**Note 1:**

These were simplified from the original relations,

$$ \ln{\gamma_1^∞} = 1 - \ln\left( \frac{V_2}{V_1} \exp{-\frac{\tau_{2,1}}{T}} \right) - \frac{V_1}{V_2} \exp{-\frac{\tau_{1,2}}{T}} $$

$$ \ln{\gamma_2^∞} = 1 - \ln\left( \frac{V_1}{V_2} \exp{-\frac{\tau_{1,2}}{T}} \right) - \frac{V_2}{V_1} \exp{-\frac{\tau_{2,1}}{T}} $$

where $\gamma_1^∞$, $\gamma_2^∞$, $V_1$, $V_2$, and $T$ are positive and $\tau_{1,2}$ and $\tau_{1,2}$ are real.  Above,
$$v = \frac{V_1}{V_2},\, a=\frac{\tau_{1,2}}{T},\, b=\frac{\tau_{2,1}}{T},\, y_i = \ln{\gamma_i^∞} - (1 + \ln \frac{V_i}{V_{3-i}}) $$

## Note 2:

Substituting and reducing yields the equivalent problem:

$$ (x - y)c^{\exp(-x)} = z $$

(where $x = x_1, y=y_2, c=\exp(v), z=e^{-y_1}/v$).

Can this equation be solved for x?

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much as the expressions of the binary activity coefficients at infinite dilution from Wilson or T-K-Wilson models.

I have been facing the same problem as you long time ago and, unfortunately, I did not find any way to solve it (except, as you did, eliminating one of the $x$ and be left with one single equation in terms of the remaining variable). To tell the truth, I was hoping to get solutions in terms of generalized Lambert function. This is probably why were generated nomograms for this class of models.

Then, I gave up and just used numerical methods.

But, you must also know that there could be multiple solutions to the problem.

Comment: That's right.  I was hoping to obtain explicit interaction energy expressions from the infinite dilution activity coefficients of binary Wilson mixtures.  But I've stuck on this equation.  It does look vaguely Lambertian, except the tetration in the middle.